# Non square linear system with two unknowns

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I want to know under what conditions exists at least one solution for the following system
$$Ax + By = C$$
where $A$ is $p \times q$ matrix, $B$ is $p \times q$ matrix and $C$ is a vector of size $p$. Uniqueness doesn't matter. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The system has a solution if and only if the system

$$\begin{bmatrix}A& B\end{bmatrix}z=C$$ has a solution. Of course, the solution vector $z$ will have $2q$ entries, and if written as

$$z=\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}$$
then $z$ is a solution of the second system if and only if $x, y$ are solutions to the original system.

---

You can interpret this result by looking at $\{Ax|x\in\mathbb R^p\}$ as "the set of all linear combinations of columns of $A$". Then, $By$ is the general element of the set of all linear combinations of columns from $B$, which means that $Ax+By$ can be any linear combination of columns from both $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Is there anay rank condition on $A$, $B$ and $C$ to ensure the existence? thanks.

Comment: @Gustave Once you have the system $\begin{bmatrix} A&B\end{bmatrix}z=C$, you can use the standard theorems from linear algebra to determine when a solution exists. Also, "rank condition" on $C$ makes little sense, since $C$ is a vector, not a matrix.

Comment: Thank you a lot sir.